# Character moves uncontrollably when grabs an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Something really weird is happening to my game. When the character grabs an object, he starts to move uncontrollably and the inputs are inverted. For example, if I press the button that makes the character to go to right, he goes to left and vice versia. I don't know what's going on. The object has a box collider. The player has a sphere collider attached to him which is triggered.

The bigger this object, the faster the character moves. I really don't know. I use this code to pick the object.

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
    {
        Player.PodeLargar = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider" && !Player.Segurando && !ItemEmCima)
    {
        StartCoroutine(PegarItem());
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider" && Player.Segurando && !ItemEmCima)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Player.PosicionarItem(this.transform));
        ItemEmCima = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider" && Player.Segurando && !ItemEmCima /*|| other.gameObject.tag != "Espaço1.1" || other.gameObject.tag != "Incisivo"*/)
    {
        Player.PodeLargar = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider" && !Player.Segurando && ItemEmCima)
    {
        EmCima = this.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
        LugarErrado = false;
        StartCoroutine(PegarDaBancada(EmCima));
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
    {
        Player.PodeLargar = true;
    }
}

//----Coroutines---------------------------------------------------------
IEnumerator PegarItem()
{
    //Instantiate(DenteRespectivo, ColliderTrans.position, ColliderTrans.rotation, ColliderTrans.transform);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    Player.Segurando = true;
}

IEnumerator PegarDaBancada(GameObject Objeto)
{
    Objeto.transform.parent = ColliderTrans.transform;
    Objeto.transform.position = ColliderTrans.position;
    Objeto.transform.rotation = ColliderTrans.rotation;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    Player.Segurando = true;
    ItemEmCima = false;
}
```

Comment: Can't really see any reason for that behaviour in your code since I can't see your movement code. A far-fetched guess would be that it's due to you setting the item as child to the player. Items seem to be triggers though, so shouldn't affect it unless you have some magic movement code.

Comment: Your trigger code reads oddly. You have 2 separate sections for "if Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider" && Player.Segurando && !ItemEmCima" and 2 more for Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider" && !Player.Segurando && !ItemEmCima" .. Id suggest consolodation or refactoring to make it more readable.. as it maybe the reason you're getting odd behavior is actually some of these things shouldnt be happening

Comment: Please include the code for `Player.PosicionarItem`

Comment: Man I've solved  the problem. I just dismarked the box collider. Now it works fine!